# Реализация метода time.sleep с помощью async/await

Tags: python, async-await

Необходимо реализовать функцию, которая бы через некоторое время выполняла определенные действия. Однако при вызове этой функции, выполнение кода не должно останавливаться. Как можно это реализовать? Python 3.5

Небольшой пример:

```
import time

    def my_func():
         time.sleep(120)
         #какие-то ещё действия

#код
my_func()
#код, который должен быть исполнен без остановки #методом sleep()
```

Comment: Заголовок вопроса (на который можно ответить ссылкой на asyncio.sleep()) отличается от содержимого вопроса, на который можно ответить, используя threading.Timer, asyncio's loop.call_at() или аналоги из tkinter, gtk, twisted, etc. See [Postponing functions in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5177439/4279)

Comment: процессы/потоки

Answer (score -1):

Для вашей задачи не какой async/await не нужен, достаточно потока:

```
from threading import Thread
import time


def my_func():
    time.sleep(12)
    print('timer done')


Thread(target=my_func).start()

for n in range(15):
    print('что то делаем')
    time.sleep(1)
```